# I have changed the permission Magento2 files with sudo command now website not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, magento, amazon-ec2, rds

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZoJu.png)

I have installed magento2 on aws

Comment: Why don't you revert back to previous permission with sudo command ?

Comment: Now new error coming I can manage to login to admin panel but giving me error something went wrong

Comment: Does anyone knows how many .htaccess file is in magento2 ?